# Woocommerce: Send JSON to external sever after checkout

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I need your help with woocommerce 3.3.
I need to send JSON with order data after checkout with this format:

```
json = {
    “partner”:
{
    “aid”:<APIUserID>,
    “password”:<APIUserPass>
    },
    “customer”:
    {
        “client_name”:<CustomerName>,
        “client_lastname”:<CustomerLastName>,
        “client_phone”:<7-999-9999999>,
        “client_email”:<email>,
        “promo”:< coupon_codes>
        },
    “items”:
    [
{“prod_id”:<ProductID_1>,”quantity”:<Quantity_1>},
…
{“prod_id”:<ProductID_2>,”quantity”:<Quantity_2>}
]
}
```

Google didn't help me. 
So this is all I have at this moment:

```
<?php
function action_woocommerce_new_order( $order_id ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $order->get_billing_phone();
    $order->get_billing_email();

    // I need to get products list
    // And I need to send this to another server with JSON

    };

    // add the action
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Where do you want to send the data to? An external server? Have a look at libraries like Guzzle

Comment: Yes, to external server. I don't know how can I create JSON structure like in my example.

Comment: Have you tried using `json_encode`?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to create arrays to form the correct structure for json

Comment: What have you tried? Creating the array should not be that hard, and without some more knowledge about your system, we cannot do that for you

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Here is [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bMZiUMci)

Comment: And what is the problem with the code from your pastebin? Why don't you add it to your question to keep all code in one place?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Products use this:

```
$line_items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $line_items as $item ) {
  // product
  $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

  // now you can get the data from $product array
}
```

Than put your data in an array with your format and use "json_decode()"

Edit:
put your data like this in an array:

```
$my_array = array(
'partner' => array(
                'aid' => '123',
                'passwd' => '123',
            ),
'customer' => array(
                'client_name' => 'abs',
                'client_lastname' => '123'
            ),
 // ....and so on ....
);
```

than convert the array to json:

```
$to_json = json_encode($my_array);
```

check the result:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($to_json);
echo '</pre>';
```

it should looks like this:

```
string(97) "{
    "partner":{
        "aid":"123",
         "passwd":"123"
    },
    "customer":{
        "client_name":"abs",
        "client_lastname":"123"
    }
}"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!
>Than put your data in an array with your format and use "json_decode()"
How can I create JSON structure like in my example?